# Can import dataset into RStudio but can't read file

Tags: r

I can see the table of the data set on the upper right of Data.
My code is currently:

```
file.exists(C:/Hollywood.xlsx)?
```

to see if RStudio is picking up on it.
I get an error message of

> "Incomplete expression: file.exists(C:Hollywood.xlsx)?"

To take a look at the working directory, I'm doing Session>Set Working Directory>Source File Location and get "The currently active source file is not saved so doesn't have a directory to change into." If I instead try Session>Set Working Directory>To Files Pane Location, I get setwd(~) and the following is what I get and subsequent code I try:

```
setwd("/Users/FridasSlave/Downloads/Hollywood")
#Error in setwd("/Users/FridasSlave/Downloads/Hollywood") : 
#  cannot change working directory

getwd(Hollywood)
# Error in getwd(Hollywood) : unused argument (Hollywood)
getwd("Hollywood")
#Error in getwd("Hollywood") : unused argument ("Hollywood")
```

If I try Session>Set Working Directory>Choose Directory, I can get to my Downloads folder but the individual files are all not there.
What am I doing wrong?
(And yes, I'm very new to R.)

I have all my relevant paths and code above.

Comment: (1) Always quote your string literals, as IRTFM states in more details. There are _some_ functions in R that do not require it (i.e., to reference column names within a frame), but I've never seen one function that does this "non-standard evaluation" (NSE) on _paths_. (2) `getwd(.)` never takes an argument; since you already demonstrate use of `setwd` albeit with a different argument, I do not know what is expected to happen here. `getwd` is a _getter_, `setwd` is a setter, period.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling down the list of problems:

1. I hope you didn't put a `?` at the end of an R command. It's true that it looks like it would be a question if you were talking to a person, but that's not the case.
2. The argument to file.exists should be a character value. `C:/Hollywood.xlsx` is not recognized by the R interpreter as a character value because there are no quotes around it. It's possible that at that point you could have gotten success with

   `file.exists("Hollywood.xlsx")` # if it is in the current working directory
3. From your use of "~" and `setwd("/Users/FridasSlave/Downloads/Hollywood")` I'm guessing that you are on a Mac. Your question should probably have included that as a specific note. (Which further raises the issue why you would use a Windows file spcification if you are on a Mac?
4. The reason for the error from `setwd("/Users/FridasSlave/Downloads/Hollywood")` is not obvious, but maybe you misspelled part of the path or maybe it should have been `setwd("/Users/FridasSlave/Downloads/")`.
5. Trying `getwd(Hollywood)` you again failed to include quotes around the argument. And why would you even want an argument if you want information about the current working directory? Should have just been `getwd()`

Comment: *"you are on a mac"* ... on my windows machines (10 and 11), `"/Users/r2/Downloads/"` is real. The fact that it's missing the `C:` is not a problem.

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY What about “~”? I only see that on my Mac and Linux boxes as a synonym for user-home. But my last use of a Windoze device was roughly 10 years ago so I could well be outdated.

Comment: Even on windows, `list.files("~")` works. Whether it ultimately points to `"C:/Users/r2/"` (my preference) or `"C:/Users/r2/Documents/"` (windows default, I think) is up to user-configuration. I don't know how long it's been there, tbh, I can't say it's "always been there". \*shrug\*

Comment: I did say it was a guess and asked for clarification, but maybe clarification was not needed?